# Auth0 react post-login event

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

I would like to trigger a programmatic event on my React application,

I saw on the doc it is possible to use a [post-login event](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/flows-and-triggers/login-flow/event-object), which is exactly what I am looking for.

My question: is it implemented out-of-the-box by the [library auth0 for react](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react)?

As of today I'm using the last version `2.0.1`

Here is a code sample that could add some context:

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Auth0Provider, AppState } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

function Auth0ProviderWithHistory({ children }: Props) {
  const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
  const audience = process.env.REACT_APP_API_AUDIENCE;

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState?: AppState) => {
    navigate(
      appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname + window.location.search
    );
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
        audience: audience
      }}
     // postLoginTriggerEvent={(event) => {triggerAnalytics(event)}} Is what I am looking for
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
}

export default Auth0ProviderWithHistory;
```

The function `onRedirectCallback` is not good enough because triggered not only after a user log in but also when he is already logged in and reload the application.